# Difference between "Sustainable energy" and "Renewable Energy"

Tags: differences

What is the difference between "Sustainable Energy" and "Renewable Energy?". Those words seem to be used interchangeably. I want to know its true difference amongst the two words. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What research have you conducted into this question yourself? I would look at sites concerned with ecology and the like rather than here. And please finish reading the [Tour].

Answer (score 1):

> Energy is sustainable if it "meets the needs of the present without compromising the ability of future generations to meet their own needs" *(Kutscher, C.F.; Milford, J.B.; Kreith, F. (2019). Principles of Sustainable Energy Systems. Mechanical and Aerospace Engineering Series (Third ed.). CRC Press. ISBN 978-0-429-93916-7.)*

> Renewable energy is energy that is collected from renewable resources that are naturally replenished on a human timescale. It includes sources such as sunlight, wind, the movement of water, and geothermal heat. *(Ellabban, Omar; Abu-Rub, Haitham; Blaabjerg, Frede (2014). "Renewable energy resources: Current status, future prospects and their enabling technology". Renewable and Sustainable Energy Reviews. 39: 748–764 [749]. doi:10.1016/j.rser.2014.07.113.)*

> Although most renewable energy sources are sustainable, some are not. For example, some biomass sources are considered unsustainable at current rates of exploitation. *(Harvey, Chelsea; Heikkinen, Niina (23 March 2018). "Congress Says Biomass Is Carbon Neutral but Scientists Disagree - Using wood as fuel source could actually increase CO2 emissions". Scientific American.)*